# dplyr R group totals differ between factors

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been trying to summarise a dataset in R all day with dplyr and seem to either a) be getting inconsistent results, or b) have stopped thinking straight!

My dataset 'resi_type (see below) captures population figures and garbage generation rates for a city. There are three levels at which I'm trying to summarise these figures:
the geo_zone, the constituency, and socio-economic areas (low, medium, high). These are in order of size e.g. There are 437 individual areas that fall within one of the three socio-economic classes; these are all in only one of the six constituencies; and the six constituencies lie within one of the four geo_zones.

I have been pretty impressed with the speed and ease of dplyr, and have been using this to summarise my data and add in a few calculated values. For example, summarising the whole data set at the constituency level:

```
constit_sum <- 
  resi_type %.%
  group_by(constit, grouped_types) %.%
  summarise(area = sum(area),
            constit_pop = first(constit_pop),
            wg_rate = first(per_capita)) %.% 
  mutate(prop = area/sum(area)*100) %.% 
  mutate(pop = (prop/100)*constit_pop) %.% 
  mutate(waste = (wg_rate*pop)/1000)
```

This produces a nice table for me. If I sum the rows , I get my total population of 939,370, and a total 'waste' production of 744.3238 (tonnes).

Now when attempting to produce a summary at the County-level I've been playing with two chunks of code. This one produces the same results as above when I sum across rows e.g. total population of 939,370, and a total 'waste' production of 744.3238 (tonnes):

```
county_sum <- 
  constit_sum %.%
  group_by(grouped_types) %.%
  summarise(area = sum(area),
            waste = sum(waste))
```

However, the following code chunk which is a slightly different approach to solving the same problem, produces different results e.g. total population of 939,370, and a total 'waste' production of 757.8447 (tonnes)

```
county_sum2 <-
  resi_type %.%
  group_by(grouped_types) %.%
  summarise(area = sum(area),
                    wg_rate = first(per_capita)) %.% 
  mutate(prop = area/sum(area)*100) %.% 
  mutate(pop = (prop/100)*939370) %.%
  mutate(waste = (wg_rate*pop)/1000)
```

I seem to be going around in circles as I assume that no matter how you slice the data the total waste generated should be the same no matter at what level of analysis I am undertaking? Or perhaps there is something wrong with my code? I've literally gone cross-eyed and I'm hoping someone may be able to shed some light on this for me?!

Here's hoping...!

Thanks in advance

Marty

Dataset = resi_type

```
    structure(list(geo_zone = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Mainland North", 
"Mainland South", "Mainland West", "Mombasa Island"), class = "factor"), 
    constit = c("likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "likoni", 
    "likoni", "likoni", "likoni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", "nyali", 
    "nyali", "kisauni", "nyali", "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "nyali", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", 
    "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "kisauni", "jomvu", 
    "jomvu", "jomvu", "nyali", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", 
    "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", 
    "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", 
    "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "changamwe", 
    "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", 
    "changamwe", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", 
    "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", "jomvu", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", "changamwe", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", 
    "mvita", "mvita", "mvita", "mvita"), constit_pop = c(166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 
    166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 166008L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 
    194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 
    194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 
    194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 
    185990L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 185990L, 185990L, 194065L, 
    194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 
    185990L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 
    194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 194065L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    185990L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 132692L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 132692L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 
    117487L, 117487L, 117487L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 
    132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 132692L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 143128L, 
    143128L, 143128L), grouped_types = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("low", 
    "medium", "high"), class = "factor"), area = c(191461L, 168928L, 
    881707L, 43546L, 39139L, 98823L, 22327L, 86611L, 58418L, 
    60798L, 56243L, 239978L, 4088L, 4184L, 39670L, 32892L, 33701L, 
    51806L, 52514L, 50464L, 128450L, 36563L, 7722L, 242320L, 
    4166L, 36158L, 70785L, 43925L, 70614L, 28876L, 40984L, 725320L, 
    628762L, 78149L, 39327L, 1040985L, 286288L, 324669L, 237726L, 
    269182L, 389987L, 291501L, 6729L, 322114L, 154042L, 73540L, 
    421880L, 7814L, 31154L, 52520L, 20187L, 570102L, 143059L, 
    1032717L, 238886L, 487527L, 412965L, 44010L, 337910L, 103214L, 
    898486L, 257766L, 2346497L, 40165L, 286848L, 15204L, 14741L, 
    33759L, 31367L, 10659L, 16966L, 8623L, 35058L, 5673L, 68267L, 
    705371L, 949977L, 486446L, 294029L, 134848L, 302860L, 33036L, 
    53250L, 68122L, 62749L, 68404L, 73999L, 132052L, 276413L, 
    96435L, 93399L, 11964L, 63652L, 43107L, 41734L, 8942L, 106987L, 
    73466L, 15260L, 34230L, 26790L, 102071L, 66920L, 53821L, 
    41854L, 112277L, 35686L, 121283L, 442860L, 161307L, 268652L, 
    99335L, 132137L, 44353L, 12662L, 46855L, 82968L, 107930L, 
    508985L, 62745L, 938082L, 22117L, 936310L, 94858L, 73017L, 
    52606L, 6627L, 24497L, 259809L, 232665L, 54735L, 198384L, 
    625396L, 210216L, 69182L, 122513L, 116519L, 615935L, 183869L, 
    191174L, 46026L, 45894L, 115477L, 526100L, 620402L, 409119L, 
    61246L, 50378L, 382692L, 226353L, 30415L, 140897L, 380308L, 
    278496L, 140738L, 90931L, 309373L, 675839L, 126616L, 28072L, 
    359436L, 265410L, 61959L, 14987L, 163470L, 63586L, 202991L, 
    17073L, 153207L, 10945L, 32625L, 6528L, 66156L, 41513L, 71556L, 
    59877L, 1672723L, 83184L, 127108L, 225371L, 7148L, 55633L, 
    23490L, 33440L, 31874L, 57616L, 141644L, 4041L, 16330L, 24755L, 
    21670L, 17487L, 18316L, 2185L, 57400L, 65359L, 2195L, 3315L, 
    1921L, 149230L, 27015L, 125189L, 8282L, 123498L, 43192L, 
    28750L, 53547L, 90610L, 111713L, 1389550L, 46932L, 65567L, 
    34963L, 157530L, 495876L, 35865L, 69871L, 33037L, 15238L, 
    187162L, 25614L, 222164L, 208159L, 35492L, 74961L, 119257L, 
    338205L, 157776L, 269244L, 7808L, 81022L, 117785L, 53097L, 
    88359L, 120146L, 25215L, 5604L, 44767L, 107211L, 48531L, 
    62563L, 30239L, 39535L, 18375L, 50473L, 118626L, 6583L, 25521L, 
    83484L, 37988L, 142569L, 60286L, 29201L, 21472L, 45229L, 
    218326L, 136081L, 72108L, 44545L, 419200L, 118830L, 293110L, 
    28082L, 34409L, 28544L, 70845L, 883447L, 50206L, 501740L, 
    292555L, 11381L, 760137L, 46906L, 45658L, 12068L, 31536L, 
    26448L, 66957L, 60306L, 63473L, 92440L, 33038L, 40690L, 4358L, 
    15420L, 35874L, 241844L, 103774L, 231520L, 55938L, 4980L, 
    15129L, 71766L, 15052L, 51907L, 58131L, 11222L, 84234L, 18250L, 
    55818L, 354058L, 426951L, 78515L, 69888L, 61814L, 63906L, 
    10022L, 12016L, 17379L, 41985L, 52158L, 26534L, 6521L, 24839L, 
    52534L, 6259L, 12217L, 27762L, 21291L, 13541L, 49876L, 10837L, 
    452375L, 71490L, 51393L, 138363L, 141327L, 22491L, 14763L, 
    24576L, 49290L, 103754L, 10742L, 85254L, 13606L, 3300L, 18141L, 
    16879L, 35271L, 82284L, 695830L, 4878L, 18671L, 2561L, 21473L, 
    31871L, 5064L, 37972L, 11353L, 13481L, 60994L, 10852L, 4068L, 
    15985L, 1380L, 90067L, 182569L, 111214L, 373818L, 29520L, 
    92995L, 15263L, 51544L, 14380L, 62169L, 31736L, 33060L, 34099L, 
    22353L, 3371L, 4004L, 130913L, 6064L, 35123L, 30165L, 32239L, 
    27727L, 65874L, 17705L, 15342L, 27021L, 32604L, 48038L, 43721L, 
    21798L, 23312L, 44106L, 34939L, 16593L, 5387L, 12524L, 88162L, 
    18039L, 475786L, 5763L, 8036L, 79110L, 9284L, 38040L, 63066L, 
    4939L, 5665L, 47305L, 47126L, 32030L, 10339L, 33543L, 6560L, 
    119694L, 45586L, 62892L, 56458L, 20836L, 38241L, 132671L, 
    4101L, 3229L, 32904L, 6779L, 21641L, 95824L, 182038L, 33146L, 
    11859L, 17811L, 19589L, 28067L, 92553L, 17485L, 25332L, 39660L, 
    4862L, 13969L, 18905L, 37109L, 37983L, 21651L), per_capita = c(0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 1.33, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 
    0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 1.33, 0.55, 0.89, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 1.33, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 
    0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.89, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 
    1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.55, 0.55, 1.33, 0.89, 
    0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    1.33, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0.55, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.89)), .Names = c("geo_zone", 
"constit", "constit_pop", "grouped_types", "area", "per_capita"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -437L))
```

Comment: What version of dplyr are you using? Perhaps you should update to the latest CRAN version. I'm asking because you're using `%.%` which is deprecated (replaced by `%>%`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loading the data to check, the difference appears to be that in the first version, waste is defined (after all the mutations) as:

```
area / sum(area) * constit_pop * wg_rate / 1000
```

Whereas in the second it's:

```
area / sum(area) * 939370 * wg_rate / 1000
```

In the first version, you seem to be applying a percentage to an incomplete population, which may be why you are getting a lower number.

#### Update 1

After playing with your data a bit, I believe the 757 number is more accurate. You treat the `area` value as an actual size, and use that to partition the locality. Since your area proportion sums to 1, and you wish to apply that percentage to allocate population, you have to apply it to the **total** population, and not the total population of the constituencies, which is less than or equal to the total. That is why you were getting an answer less than 757.

What I would recommend is mapping out on paper how you would calculate the total waste for an area from the data you have, and using that to create a column of actual (or expected) waste. Once you have waste per area, summarizing it should be a breeze with `dplyr`. If I understand your problem correctly, it may look something like the following. There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but the following should be relative clear, I hope.

```
new_resi <- tbl_df(resi_type)
total_pop <- group_by(new_resi, constit_pop) %>% summarize() %>% sum()
new_resi <- new_resi %>% mutate(prop = area / sum(area),
area_pop = total_pop * prop, waste = per_capita * area_pop / 1000)
```

Now you should be able to aggregate on whatever axis you want:

```
> sum(new_resi$waste)
[1] 757.8447

> new_resi %>% group_by(constit) %>% summarize(sum(waste))
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

    constit sum(waste)
1 changamwe   43.77569
2     jomvu   58.32272
3   kisauni  177.14872
4    likoni  122.57831
5     mvita  102.38562
6     nyali  253.63362
> new_resi %>% group_by(geo_zone) %>% summarize(sum(waste))
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

        geo_zone sum(waste)
1 Mainland North   430.7823
2 Mainland South   122.5783
3  Mainland West   102.0984
4 Mombasa Island   102.3856
> 430.7823+122.5783+102.0984+102.3856
[1] 757.8446
> new_resi %>% group_by(grouped_types) %>% summarize(sum(waste))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  grouped_types sum(waste)
1           low   276.8951
2        medium   199.9059
3          high   281.0437
```

Comment: Hey, it doesn't seem to be a problem with my use of %.%; but @Avraham your comment struck a chord. I am applying the percentage to an incomplete population. I know the total population, and I know that the individual constituency population sums to the total. What I don't know is the population of each socio-economic group within each constituency - hence having to calculate it based on the proportion of the area within each constituency covered by each socio-economic type. I can't see anyway around this at the moment, can you advise how I might ensure that these sum correctly? thanks

Comment: @marty_c What exactly do `area` and `per_capita` represent? Is `area` the actual size of the demense or is it an identifier like a [zip code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code) in the US? Is `per_capita` the number of tons of garbage generated per-persom, per annum?

Comment: Yes area is the physical size of the area (m2) and per_capita is the weight of waste produce per person/ per day e.g. 0.55kg

Comment: @marty_c That's what I thought. Please see the update in the answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Exactly what I was after, I really appreciate your inputs. cheers